# Imperative be-passive: "Please be advised"

Tags: adjectives, passive-voice, past-participles, imperatives

Is *Please be advised* an imperative passive, or rather *advised* is an adjective?

Comment: It's a passive imperative clause.

Comment: Other verbs include "warn", as in "Be warned!" ("Heed this warning") / "intimidate", as in "Don't be intimidated" ("Don't allow yourself to be intimidated") / "see", as in "Don't be seen" ("Avoid being seen") / "check", as in "Get yourself checked out by your own doctor" ("Get your own doctor to check you out").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare

Please be **cautious/aware/vigilant** - adjectives. They can all be preceded by "very" but the passive agent, e.g. "by me" cannot be inserted.

Please be **very cautious/aware/vigilant**

*Please be **cautious/aware/vigilant by me**

Please be **advised** - passive form, past participle. "Very" cannot be added and passive agent, e.g. "by me" can be inserted.

*Please be **very advised**

Please be **advised by me.**

Comment: What other verbs allow an imperative with a be-passive?

Comment: @GJC You obviously do not want me to list every possible English verb in every conceivable context, do you? It would take several days and you would not remember them all... All transitive verbs can be used in the passive, although whether you would use some of them in this construction is doubtful.